# Can I make yum override /etc/yum/vars/ contents, or use a different way to write in a default minor version?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

I've got a system that has to stay on CentOS 7.3 in order for some SAN FibreChannel software to work. I know in theory if something works in any 7.x it should work in the latest 7.x, but the manufacturer is very clear we can't go to 7.9. Long term we're planning to transition away from this manufacturer and from FibreChannel all together.

If I run `sudo yum update` it tries to update the system to 7.9

If I run `sudo yum update --releasever=7.3.1611` it tries to keep to 7.3 updates, which fails unless I add vault entries to `/etc/yum.repos.d/` files, which is fine. But I'd like 7.3 to be the default, in case I or someone else forgets and runs `yum update` sometime in the future

If I create `/etc/yum/vars/releasever` with the contents `7.3.1611` then that becomes the default behaviour, and `sudo yum update` will try to keep to 7.3 updates

But, and here's my issue, sometimes I'd like to install something and use the main 7.x repos. If I run `sudo yum update --releasever=7` while my `/etc/yum/vars/releasever` exists, then the command line option doesn't overrule the default, and it behaves exactly as if I ran `sudo yum update`.

So now if I want to update to the latest version of Firefox, I have to run `echo '7' | sudo tee /etc/yum/vars/releasever && sudo yum update firefox ; echo '7.3.1611' | sudo tee /etc/yum/vars/releasever` which works but is hacky. Is there some way I can specify a yum variable when I call yum in a way that overrides the contents of `/etc/yum/vars`? Or is there somewhere else I can specify the yum version, somewhere that can be overridden when I run yum? Or is there a better way for me to be doing this so I can install packages without risking breaking everything if someone runs `yum update`?

I read that the version can also be read from `/etc/yum.conf` but I tried adding a line with `distroverpkg=7.3.1611` to that and removing `/etc/yum/vars/releasever` and it doesn't seem to do anything, and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210721171741/https://avinetworks.com/docs/latest/how-to-tie-a-system-to-a-specific-update/) said that method only works for licensed RHEL and not CentOS.

Comment: The man for yum says
distroverpkg The package used by yum to determine the "version" of the distribution, this sets $releasever for use in config files. This can be any installed package.  Default is `'system-release(releasever)', 'redhat-release'`. Yum will now look at the version provided by the provide, and if that is non-empty then will use the full V(-R), otherwise it uses the version of the package.
You can see what provides this manually by using: `"yum whatprovides 'system-release(releasever)' centos-release"` and you can see what $releasever is most easily by using: `"yum version"`